WP Woocommerce Elementor custom query product_cat sorting
I am using elementor and woocommerce in WP, and I've build a page with the loopgrid widget, in it I have set up a loop that returns my product categories. By default the product categories only have name and ID, meaning by default I can only sort by either name and category.
Using ACF fields I've added a number field named "num_sort".
I know elementor has custom query filters with this guide https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/ and I've tried using a simple function that fetches the value in "num_sort" that then I can insert in the widget. However it doesn't seem to work, which I'm certain I've done it wrong.
function numberSorting( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'num_sort' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/sort_by_number', 'numberSorting' );


function numberSorting( $query ) {
    // Check if the query is for product categories
    if ( isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) && $query->query['post_type'] === 'product' && isset( $query->query['taxonomy'] ) && $query->query['taxonomy'] === 'product_cat' ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'num_sort' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/sort_by_number', 'numberSorting' );


Welcome! While this may answer the question, edit the question to explain what you did and why it should work.

Thank you for spending time helping me. However it didn't work.

Hi, please read how to answer
